# update the case status depend on task regarding status

Tags: c#, dynamic, plugins

I have this code below. If all the task is reject =>> the case status=>> reject, but i want if i choose other like approve or pending it it gonna do the same with case status. For ex:like i choose csu task status == complete =>> csu case status== complete

```
                Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["target"];
           
                Entity entity = service.Retrieve("task", target.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
               
                EntityReference regardingCaseRef = entity["regardingobjectid"] as EntityReference;
                Entity regardingCase = service.Retrieve(regardingCaseRef.LogicalName, regardingCaseRef.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
                
                QueryExpression qeRelatedTasks = new QueryExpression("task");
                qeRelatedTasks.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
                qeRelatedTasks.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, regardingCaseRef.Id));
                EntityCollection relatedTasks = service.RetrieveMultiple(qeRelatedTasks);

                if (AllTaskReject(relatedTasks))
                {
                    trace.Trace("status check");
                    regardingCase["cos_csucasestatus"] = new OptionSetValue(769190006);
                    trace.Trace("status check 2");

                    service.Update(regardingCase);
                    trace.Trace("status check 3");
                    /* Entity incident = new Entity("incident");
                 incident.Id = regardingCaseRef.Id;
                 trace.Trace("1");
                 incident["cos_csucasestatus"] = new OptionSetValue(769190006);
                 service.Update(incident);*/
                    // regardingCase.Attributesk["cos_csucasestatus"] = new OptionSetValue(769190006);
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }



        }



    }
    public bool AllTaskReject(EntityCollection relatedTasks)
    {
        //check all the the task if rejected continue if on task not rejected do nothing

        if (relatedTasks.Entities.All(x => x.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("cos_csutaskstatus")?.Value == 769190003))
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What does _"but i want if i choose other like approve or sth it it gonna do"_ mean? In particular,  what is _"sth_"?

Comment: like i choose csu task status == complete =>> csu case status== complete

Comment: Currently it's hard to tell where your question text ends and where the code begins exactly, can you rephrase and format the question a little to make it readable?